# How to check whether a string includes a given string variable?

Tags: ruby, string, variables, include

I'm writing a method that checks whether a number contains a digit within a given range.

I've got the number in string form between the two given indexes. I now just need to check whether it includes the given digit.

Assuming digit is an integer when passed to the method
Why does `digit.to_s` and then `number.include?(digit)` not working?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your code snippet with what you have tried? If you're calling `digit.to_s` and then passing `digit` to the `include?` method, it doesn't work because `to_s` doesn't mutate the original digit (you'd have to save the result off to a variable, or call `digit.to_s` directly as an argument to `include?`).

Comment: It would be best if you provided a [mcve]. You'd get feedback on your range-checking method as well.

Comment: `to_s` doesn't modify the receiver.

Comment: What kind of "range"? Range of digits? Range of numbers? Can you provide a full example?

Comment: And what are the "indexes" for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
number.include?(digit.to_s)
```

You didn't convert the digit to string.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it would be something silly like that!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any conversions to String.

Here's a method that doesn't:

```
def digits_in_range(int, range)
  int.digits & range.to_a
end
```

This uses set intersection (`&`) to determine if any digits fall within the range. It returns the intersection:

```
digits_in_range(12345, 4..9) #=> [4, 5]
```

If you just want a boolean `true` or `false`:

```
digits_in_range(12345, 5..9).any? #=> true
digits_in_range(32645, 7..9).any? #=> false
```

Comment: Note that the `digits` method was introduced in Ruby 2.4

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string-number `'2343434'` within a given range (0..2 for example) contains the digit `2`:

```
'2343434'[0..2].match?(/#{2}/) #=> true
```

Assuming you're passing in a number hence the interpolation (or you could use `to_s` instead).

Comment: You've made a different, but equally valid, assumption about OP's use of "range."